# Cant set background in Corona sdk

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Have a problem, when i set background in Corona SDK by this code or any other:

```
local background = display.newRect(0,0, display.contentWidth ,display.contentHeight)
background:setFillColor( 255, 255, 255 )
```

(width may be hardcoded), the simulator then show me this image:

http://apikabu.ru/img_n/2014-02_3/7mw.jpg

One more same picture, if link above is broken

http://tinypic.com/r/2vmy3qr/8

What i do wrong ?
Why x,y coordinates wrong ? If i try to put image or text coordinates be wrong too.

One more for those who don't understand question:
In this picture we have coordinates left=0, top=0 and text out of display

http://tinypic.com/r/34grcao/8

And here coordinates left=50, top=10, and now we see text, but why left-top corner is not left=0, top=0 ?

http://tinypic.com/r/259jqfb/8

Thanks for answers!

Comment: in corona graphics 2.0 to set color use values 0 - 1 rather than 0 - 255

Comment: Thank you, but answer not resolve my problem

Comment: Your image link is broken.

Comment: It may be an issue with config.lua. Try to run the code without config.lua. If it works fine, then please post the code inside config.lua.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but nothing change
(add 1 more image link if first broken)

Comment: Why x and y coordinates start not in working surface? (in this case a display device)
So how u see coordinates x=0 and y=0 its not top-left corner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting the location of the rect to 0, 0 -- and the "anchor point" for that rect is the center of the object. So the rect on the screen as shown is correct -- the center is at 0, 0.

To center the rect on the screen, just modify the x and y properties:

```
background.x = display.contentCenterX
background.y = display.contentCenterY
```

That should center the rect on the screen.

Corona SDK *used* to create objects with a top-left anchor point which then automatically shifted to a center anchor point. Recently that was changed so they're now created with a center anchor point.

Comment: or change anchor: background.anchorX = 0 
 background.anchorY = 0

Comment: Please, read top question now, i add some stuff!
Thanks you!
This problem not with background only. With all coordinates.

Comment: if you set x and y, you set it to anchor point, not whole image. in graphics 2.0 anchor is default at 0.5, 0.5 (center of image), so if you set x and y for an image to 0, 0  your anchor (center of image) will be at 0, 0. To set anchor to left top point, set anchorX=0, anchorY=0

Comment: Can you answer, why with text same problem ?

Comment: text is also object and also has anchor

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this in your main.lua file

```
display.setDefault("background", 255, 255, 255, 1)
```

It will set default background color for all screens.